# What does a Javascript Object.create do?

Tags: javascript

My application is using Protractor and the "Page Model" for testing. There's an external module that looks like this:

```
'use strict';

var AdminTestPage = function () {
    browser.get('/');
};

AdminTestPage.prototype = Object.create({}, {
    detailTabClear: {
        get: function () {
            element(by.id('name')).clear();
        }
    }

});

module.exports = AdminTestPage;
```

Can someone explain why the developer has used Object.create?  Is this different from just combining the first and second parts of the code?

Comment: `AdminTestPage.prototype = { detailTabClear: ... }` would do the same thing afaict.

Comment: [reference of Object.create()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

Comment: The properties in the property descriptor become non-enumerable and non-configurable by default. Maybe that was intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties in the property descriptor become *non-enumerable* and *non-configurable* by default, as explained in the documentation [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty).

So the call is the same as

```
AdminTestPage.prototype = Object.create({}, {
    detailTabClear: {
        get: function () {
            element(by.id('name')).clear();
        },
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: false
    }
});
```

What does that mean? It means that this property won't show up when you iterate over the object with `for...in` and you won't be able to delete it from the object via `delete`.

The same could have been written as

```
Object.defineProperty(AdminTestPage.prototype, 'detailTabClear', {
    get: function () {
        element(by.id('name')).clear();
    }
});
```

**Note:** This is very different from assigning the property directly. Properties created via the assignment statement (i.e. `obj.prop = foo`)` are enumerable and configurable by default.

---

Whether this was the intention of the author or not I cannot say though.

Answer (score 0):

Same question, I've got no idea why the developer decided to use `Object.create`.

`Object.create` does exactly what it says. It creates an object, in this case there is no difference from using the short hand notation...

```
AdminTestPage.prototype = {...};
```

it is exactly the same. `Object.create` is most useful when you already have a prototype of an object and want to create another "instance" of the same object because it "inherits" the prototype so you will not have to define all of its members. For example, consider this prototype...

```
var car = { make: "", model: ""};
```

Then you can create an instance of a car...

```
var subaru = Object.create(car);
```

the `subaru` variable is already a prototype of car...in OOP terms it'd be something like an instance of a car...

```
subaru.make = "Subaru";
subaru.model = "WRX";
```

Be aware that `Object.create` is not supported by all browsers

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation. In my example is there even a need for .prototype or could this be combined with the definition for the function above it ?